# Añadir estructura a JSON al recorrerlo

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un JSON que me llega de una API y necesito estructurar ese JSON para darle un formato determinado.

Mi JSON puro es este:

```
{
   "457":{
      "1":{
         "value":"4.12",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "2":{
         "value":"38.8",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "3":{
         "value":"37.2",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "4":{
         "value":"216.0",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      }
   }
}
```

Este es el JSON que necesito:

```
 {
   "1":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":4.12,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "value":1534183021,
            "type":"Integer"
         }
      }
   },
   "2":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":38.8,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "value":1534183021,
            "type":"Integer"
         }
      }
   },
   "3":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":37.2,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "value":1534183021,
            "type":"Integer"
         }
      }
   },
   "4":{
      "type":"float",
      "value":216.0,
      "metadata":{
         "timestamp":{
            "value":1534183021,
            "type":"Integer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Mi problema es que al no tener etiquetas mi JSON original no tengo claro como puedo asignarle los valores, anteriormente en estos casos he usado algo así, pero aquí no se como tratarlo.

recorrer el JSON y hacer esto.

```
var medidas_inver = {
    name: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
    type: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
    value: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
    timestamp: params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value
};
```

Como puedo conseguir esa estructura que he comentado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siendo `data` el JSON que obtienes, puedes hacer:

```js
 let data =   {
   "457":{
      "1":{
         "value":"4.12",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "2":{
         "value":"38.8",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "3":{
         "value":"37.2",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      },
      "4":{
         "value":"216.0",
         "timestamp":1534183021
      }
   }
}
var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
var finalobj = {};
    for (var e in data[key]){
     finalobj[e] = {
      type: "float"
      , value: parseFloat(data[key][e].value)
      , metadata: {
       timestamp: {
        value: parseInt(data[key][e].timestamp)
        , type: "Integer"
       }
      }
     };
    }
    console.log(finalobj);
```

Siempre que se mantenga la estructura de este JSON devuelto por la API.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, el valor de 457 no es fijo realmente es una variable que va cambiando.

Comment: @Manolait he actualizado la respuesta, debería funcionarte siempre que la estructura del JSON que obtienes sea la que indicas.

Comment: Hola, gracias con esto esta solucionado, antes has puesto otro código por si el valor era Fijo 457, podrías añadirlo tambien al post? gracias un saludo.

Comment: @Manolait simplemente es cambiar el for y poner _data[457]_ en vez de _data[key]_ (entonces también podrías eliminar la línea de **var key**)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que confundes dos cosas:

- Una estructura de datos formada por arrays y mapas, y
- Una **representación** como String de esa estructura de datos, y que coincide con la sintaxis que se usaría en Javascript para definir dicha estructura.

JSON es solo lo último; una vez que cargas la estructura en Javascript ya no trabajas con JSON sino con los arrays y mapas.

Si tienes:

```
let data = {
  "457":{
    "1":{
       "value":"4.12",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "2":{
       "value":"38.8",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "3":{
       "value":"37.2",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "4":{
       "value":"216.0",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     }
   }
};
```

con `data["457"]` tienes

```
  {
    "1":{
       "value":"4.12",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "2":{
       "value":"38.8",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "3":{
       "value":"37.2",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     },
     "4":{
       "value":"216.0",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     }
   }
```

con `data["457"]["2"]` tienes

```
     {
       "value":"38.8",
       "timestamp":1534183021
     }
```

etc.

Si quieres añadir un campo, entonces haces (p.ej).

```
data["457"]["2"].type = "float";
```

Nada de lo arriba descrito es JSON, todo es Javascript puro y duro.